# Parent Child Relation with restricted method access

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Let's assume I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface IChild
{
    IParent MyParent { get; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IParent : IChild
{
    IEnumerable<IChild> Children { get; }
}
```

In addition for the parent implementation there is the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class Parent : IParent
{
    private List<IChild> _children = new List<IChild>();

    public Parent(IParent parent, string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        MyParent = parent;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IChild> Children => _children;
    public IParent MyParent { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    protected void Add(IChild child)
    {
        _children.Add(child);
    }
    protected void Remove(IChild child)
    {
        _children.Remove(child);
    }
}
```

Now I use the following implementation based on the interfaces and abstract class above:

```
public class Tree : Parent
{
    private Branch _left;
    private Branch _right;
    private Leaf _goldenLeaf;

    public Tree(IParent parent, string name) :
        base(parent, name)
    {
        _left = new Branch(this, "left branch");
        Add(_left);
        _right = new Branch(this, "left branch");
        Add(_right);
        _goldenLeaf = new Leaf(this, "the golden leaf");
        Add(_goldenLeaf);
    }
}

public class Branch : Parent
{
    private Leaf _singleLeaf;

    public Branch(IParent parent, string name) :
        base(parent, name)
    {
        _singleLeaf = new Leaf(this, "the golden leaf");
        Add(_singleLeaf);
    }
}

public class Leaf : IChild
{
    public Leaf(IParent parent, string name)
    {
        MyParent = parent;
        Name = name;
    }

    public IParent MyParent { get; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // How can I have a method in the parent which can only be called
        // by the corresponding child. How to prevent the outside to call
        // the method "Inform" on the parent?
        MyParent.AskBeforeExecute(this, "data");
    }
}
```

The main problem I have is that I want to call a method from the parent within the "DoSomething" call which is only accessible by the children. So the **"AskBeforeExecute"** method can not be in the public interface of the IParent definition because then the "outer" world can also call this method. I am not sure if my idea can be implemented at all with interface as I have right now. Anyway I am stuck a little bit and I am looking for a better pattern or idea to handle this?

Comment: What's classified as the "outer world" in your case? If it means outside of the assembly, then maybe the `internal` keyword on a method will suffice, and cast `MyParent` to `Parent`.

Comment: @Hayden: Yes, this is what I mean with "outer world". Furthermore your suggestion would work, but I am looking for a way to avoid casting to an implementation - so just with interfaces?

Comment: I don't have enough information on the purpose of this abstraction, or what `AskBeforeExecute` is meant to play in your codebase, to give you an informed decision on how these classes should be structured. If you don't want to use a public interface to capture this method, then you can always use `Reflection` to invoke `AskBeforeExecute`. If you want me to show how this can be done, I can write an answer for this. If you provide more information on the purpose of `AskBeforExecute` or what you're trying to achieve in general, I may give a heads up on ways to restructure the classes.